# Using date in Shiny valueBox

Tags: shiny, radix

How can I show the current date in the subtitle of a Shiny valueBox?

```
output$approvalBox <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox("95",
                 "Number of School Days as of `r Sys.Date()`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste()`

```
valueBox(value = "95",
         subtitle = paste("Number of School Days as of", Sys.Date()))
```